# Omit files or directories from revision control?

Tags: origen-sdk

I'd like to omit an app-specific directory from the revision control check done by Origen:

```
origen rc mods
```

Is there something similar to a `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the following in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.unmanaged_dirs = %w(some_dir some/other/dir .some_hidden_dir)

config.unmanaged_files = %w(some_file some/other_file.blah *.blah)
```

Paths should be given relative to `Origen.root` and as this is applied within the `origen rc` command it should work with any revision control backend. Although, if you are using Git then it is recommended to just use `.gitignore`, this feature is intended to replicate that feature for lesser RC tools.

See the default list of ignored files/dirs for other examples: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/revision_control.rb#L9